# How can I attach to a sequence of xml tags more values with beautiful soup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am working with a directory of xmls documents with beautiful soup, however I would like to to add to all the tags of the document an id that help me to merge where this information came from. For example, I am reading the files as follows:

In:

```
for filepath in glob(os.path.join('../data/trainingFiles/', '*.xml')):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        content = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'lxml')
        for sentences in content.find_all("sentences"):
            print(sentences)
```

Therefore, for adding a `pandas_id` I tried to:

```
for i, sentences in enumerate(content.find_all("sentences")):
       #print('{}'.format(i))
       soup.find_all('sentence')['pandas_id'] = '{}'.format(i)
       print(sentences)
```

However, I got `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`, how can I append a same id to each element of my xml documents? At the end each xml from the directory will have attached a different id.

Answer (score 1):

The soup's [`findAll()`](https://kite.com/python/docs/BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup.findAll) method returns a list. To modify pandas_id you will need to use the following code:

```
for i, sentences in enumerate(content.find_all("sentences")):
       sentences['pandas_id'] = str(i)
       print(sentences)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, but this solution is adding a different `pandas_id` to each element of the xml. However, I would like to assign the same pandas id to the same document. Any idea of how to do it?